# Crystal Reports: Suppressing page headers with corresponding details section

Tags: crystal-reports, formula, suppress

I have a complex report with the following structure:

- PageHeaderSection1
- PageHeaderSection2
- PageHeaderSection3
- PageHeaderSection4
- PageHeaderSection5
- DetailsSection a
- DetailsSection b
- DetailsSection c
- DetailsSection d
- DetailsSection e

All sections are suppressed when empty.

Every details sections has its own header (1-a, 2-b and so on...)
I suppress the headers with some formulas and global variables and used the suppress formula of every header.

For example:

- Details section a sets global variable for header 1 to true and sets all other variables to false
- header 1 suppress formula returns value of variable for header 1

While this works fine when every details section has some data, I'm having trouble when i.e. details section b does not have any data. In this case header 2 will not be suppressed. The first page with records of details c displays the wrong header 2. Every further page of details c displays the correct header 3.

This is the formular which defines and sets all variables to false (placed in report header):

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Global BooleanVar Header1;
Global BooleanVar Header2;
Global BooleanVar Header3;
Global BooleanVar Header4;
Global BooleanVar Header5;

Header1:= False;
Header2:= False;
Header3:= False;
Header4:= False;
Header5:= False;
```

This is the formula for setting the first header which is placed inside details section a (the other formulas are similiar):

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Global BooleanVar Header1;
Global BooleanVar Header2;
Global BooleanVar Header3;
Global BooleanVar Header4;
Global BooleanVar Header5;

Header1:= True;
Header2:= False;
Header3:= False;
Header4:= False;
Header5:= False;
```

And finally the suppress formula of header 1:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Global BooleanVar Header1;
not Header1;
```

I have a formula for each details section. They set the correct header variable to true and al others to false.

Again, this works fine when all details sections have some data.
I tried adding OnLastRecord on some of the formulas, but that didn't work at all. I seem to be missing something. What do I have to do?

**UPDATE**

After the questions in the comments I want to add a few things for better understanding:

All my details sections contain a subreport each and nothing else. The main report itself has no data, only some layout features. All subreports are suppressed if empty and the details sections are also suppressed if empty.
After the questions in the comments I tried a few things:
I added a shared variable "HasSomeData". The variable is set in the subreport (I can use count() in those because the subreports have real data fields). This works fine. What still does not work is the suppressing of the report headers. I return the new shared variable in the suppress formula but it has no effect, the header is now shown everywhere. I'm still googling and trying around but would be very happy if someone would tell me what I'm missing.

Comment: how are you checking whether detail section has data or not?

Comment: I thought the formula won't start because WhilePrintingRecord will stop the formula immediately when it has no records. The variable won't ne set.

Comment: That was not my question.....how are you checking data present or not

Comment: I'm not checking it directly. My details sections only contain subreports and I suppress the subreports and the details section when empty.